# Can't Access Vmware Esxi from GUI and CLI after polling from OpenNMS

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, snmp, ubuntu-20.04, opennms

I added Vmware Esxi ip in OpenNMS and configured SNMP for the same. After successful addition of node, I also added Configuration in /usr/share/opennms/etc/vmware-config.xml ( I am running OpenNMS in Ubuntu 20.04 ) for monitoring of Vmware Esxi using Vmware Monitor.
Below is the configuration of vmware-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vmware-config>

<vmware-server hostname="<ip_address_of_vmware_esxi>" username="vmware_username" password="vmware_password"/>

</vmware-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was restored 1 hours later after removing the credentials from vmware-config.xml. Seems like the authentication parameters which has been given in .xml file has created a session letting other users to not access through their credentials.

Although any better explanations are welcomed.